# Wrap lines of a plain text with xml elements

Tags: xml, xslt, element

I have this xml input (it is a proper xml, I previously add the root tag to use the xslt).

```
<root>
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3</root>
```

And I need this output.

```
<root>
<line>Line 1</line>
<line>Line 2</line>
<line>Line 3</line></root>
```

I'm using this xslt but is producing one single line with all the three values in it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"><xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/<xsl:template match="root"><xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="text()[normalize-space()]"/></xsl:copy></xsl:template><xsl:template match="text()"><line>
  <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space()"/></line></xsl:template></xsl:stylesheet>
```

How can I fix this to achieve the expected output?

Comment: You can `tokenize` the string, with an XSLT 2 or 3 processor using the XPath `tokenize` function , with most XSLT 1 using an extension.

Comment: I've already tried with this but I get the same result.   <xsl:template match="root">
    <root>
      <xsl:call-template name="tokenize-lines">
        <xsl:with-param name="text" select="normalize-space()" />
      </xsl:call-template>
    </root>
  </xsl:template>

Comment: I would use `<xsl:for-each select="tokenize(., '&#10;')"><line><xsl:value-of select="."/></line></xsl:for-each>`.

Comment: This works with plain text, thanks. I tried it with xml body instead of "Line 1", but I get a org.xml.sax.SAXParseException. How can I fix it?

Comment: @JamesTaylor Which XSLT processor are you using (see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25245033/3016153)?

Comment: I'm testing with www.freeformatter.com

Comment: Please tell us which processor you will be using in production.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion from the comment slightly improved and morphed into a complete snippet can be tested at [this fiddle](https://martin-honnen.github.io/xslt3fiddlePWA/?xslt=%3C%3Fxml%20version%3D%221.0%22%20encoding%3D%22UTF-8%22%3F%3E%0D%0A%3Cxsl%3Astylesheet%20xmlns%3Axsl%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2FXSL%2FTransform%22%0D%0A%09xmlns%3Axs%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2001%2FXMLSchema%22%0D%0A%09exclude-result-prefixes%3D%22%23all%22%0D%0A%09version%3D%223.0%22%3E%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Aoutput%20indent%3D%22yes%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Atemplate%20match%3D%22root%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Acopy%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Afor-each%20select%3D%22tokenize%28.%2C%20%27%26%2310%3B%27%29%5Bnormalize-space%28%29%5D%22%3E%3Cline%3E%3Cxsl%3Avalue-of%20select%3D%22.%22%2F%3E%3C%2Fline%3E%3C%2Fxsl%3Afor-each%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Acopy%3E%0D%0A%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Atemplate%3E%0D%0A%20%20%0D%0A%3C%2Fxsl%3Astylesheet%3E&input=%3Croot%3E%0D%0ALine%201%0D%0ALine%202%0D%0ALine%203%3C%2Froot%3E&input-type=XML) and is e.g.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  
  <xsl:template match="root">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:for-each select="tokenize(., '&#10;')[normalize-space()]"><line><xsl:value-of select="."/></line></xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and outputs

```
<root>
   <line>Line 1</line>
   <line>Line 2</line>
   <line>Line 3</line>
</root>
```